# Wordpress Classes for Posts?

Tags: css, wordpress

Thanks in advance.

I'd like to have posts with different colored borders and headers.  It would be nice to choose a category of the post (red, blue, black, etc.) and have it change the class for that specific post.

If it were outside of dreamweaver, it would use classes.

So I could say:

```
<div class="red box">
<h3>Header</h3>
Content
</div>
```

Ideally this would work by having an option in the design view named 'classes' or 'post styles'.  I would choose 'box' and 'red', and the style would be changed.  Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked into wordpress custom keys? http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Comment: you might better post this on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you use to get the effect you want will depend based on the theme you are using.  Many theme authors will include the categories or tags from each theme as classes on the div that contains the post so if you tagged a post as "blue" or "boxed" the post div would come out classed the way you are hoping.  Then all you need to do is write some css that creates the effect you like.

```
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

If you are coding your own theme you can include the tags using this method (borrowed [from an answer by Alchymyth](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-tagcategory-name-as-css-class-in-query) here):

```
<?php $tags = get_the_tags();
if( $tags ) : ?>
  <p class="tags">
  <?php foreach( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
   <span class="<?php echo $tag->slug; ?>"><a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a></span>
  <?php } ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Great!  I hope you don't mind me asking: which file would the php go into?

Comment: Well, it will depend somewhat on the theme you are using.  The default location for the css code (the first code in my answer) is style.css in the root directory of the theme.  The other code goes in a theme template file.  Identifying which one you want may be a bit tricky if you haven't done theme modifications before. Probably the easiest thing to do is find a theme (there are many, including the default twentyeleven theme) that already provides you with tag-classes in the html.  Then all you have to do is go to Dashboard --> Appearance --> Editor and then choose the style.css file.

Comment: Also, if you like my answer you could encourage me to answer more of your questions by choosing it as *the* answer and giving it an upvote.  :)